# jsx render error with loop: elements not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am trying to loop through obj in json format I get from hitting the api. However, when I try to render it, I kept running into the error that the element is not defined.

This is my comment template return to html:

```
    return (
      <div> 
        this.state.comments.map((comment)=> (
          {comment.owner}
          {comment.text}
        )
      </div>

    );

  }
```

This is what the json file looks like:

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "owner": "user1", 
      "owner_show_url": "/u/user1/", 
      "postid": 1, 
      "text": "text1"
    }, 
    {
      "owner": "user2", 
      "owner_show_url": "/u/user2/", 
      "postid": 1, 
      "text": "text2"
    }
  ], 
  "url": "/api/v1/p/1/comments/"
}
```

this is the error i copied from the developer tool:

```
bundle.js:1490 Uncaught ReferenceError: comment is not defined
    at Comments.render (bundle.js:1490)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:7852)
    at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:7849)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:7945)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:8265)
    at workLoop (bundle.js:8289)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:6267)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:6283)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:6222)
    at performWork (bundle.js:8325)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be that you need to wrap javascript within jsx using {}:

```
{this.state.comments.map()}
```

you should also contain jsx within a parent component or a html tag (such I did here with the li as is standard when list building)

EDIT: I initialized comments state with 2 objects however your App should initialize state simply with an empty array:

```
state={
    comments:[]
 }
```

this should work (assuming your setState is being done properly):

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
    state={
        comments:[
          {owner:'owner1', text:'comment2'},
          {owner:'owner2', text:'comment2'}
        ]
     }
     render(){
        return (
            <ul> 
              {this.state.comments.map((comment)=> {
                return <li> {comment.owner} - {comment.text} </li>  
              })}
            </ul>
        );
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id='react'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you declare your state? Did you add the constructor to the code?

```js
this.state = {comments: new Comment()};
```

I also noticed that you missed some indentation. You need curly braces around `this.state...` and you also missed parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've declared state.

```
constructor() {
  this.state = { comments: [] }
}
```

Also, it would help to initialize it or at least assume an empty array if there are no values set to it yet

```
(this.state.comments || []).map(..)
```

And don't forget to wrap it with curly braces when inside the `render` function

```
{(this.state.comments || []).map(..)}
```